# Do the lyrics of Madoka Magica's two movie OPs foreshadow Rebellion's ending?

Tags: madoka-magica

To understand the question I'm asking, you will probably do need to watch the three Madoka Magica movies. I'll still try to avoid spoilers.

In order to fully understand the ending of the movie or rather, what happens next, I went back to look at possible clues that foreshadowed Rebellion's ending. The lyrics of Luminous by Claris, the OP for the first two movies, strikes me in particular:

> My faith in saving you becoming clear
>   I really hope in the beginning
>   To bring your smile back
>   Make it a true miracle
>
> The hope summoned pursued us and surpassed the world
>   The feeling to never give up connected our hearts before we knew it
>   Instead of crying, let's smile and head for tomorrow
>   Even if the oath we decided hurts and falls
>   To protect your heart
>   I'll be by your side

Now one thing to note is that, if I remember correctly, the song was released before the movie, although not too far apart. So it might be coincidental. However, these parts of the lyrics is interesting to me that this is exactly what Homura is doing by

> taking Madoka's power to recreate the universe in order to protect her ("even if the oath we decided hurts and falls") and release her from her own perceived sufferings ("to bring your smile back").

And that she would do any lengths to protect Madoka because she still thinks she can save her("my faith in saving you..."). The second OP in the third movie has these lyrics:

> You touched my heart and it shined, turning so colorful
>   So I'll Take Flight, Riding on Hope
>   Your Wishes Are Gathered Beneath the Sky That stretches Infinitely
>   and if I CAN go protect Them
>   I'll Get over the Memories of That day
>   WHEN I made ​​a Promise with you and go from the Past Now
>   to the tomorrow that no one knows about

To me, this just described exactly what happened in the ending. In that

> Everyone's memory is wiped out ("no one knows about"), Madoka's wishes to get rid of witches is also presumably granted as well, Homura turned back time for the n^100 times ("g o from the past now"), and Homura now becomes the "protector" instead of Madoka absorbing all the witches suffering ("if I can go protect them").

So does the two songs foreshadowed the ending? To me, I think that the song really did helped me to empathize with Homura despite what she did. There's more to the lyrics in my opinion, but I will keep it focused on just the ending.

Comment: There's not much point in avoiding spoilers in a question (other than the title) IMO. The title itself makes it clear that your question is about Rebellion's ending. Anyone who clicks it despite that is asking to be spoiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could not be planned to foreshadow Rebelion for a very simple reason: [Urobuchi (author of the story) did not plan for Rebelion when writing the series](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Gen_Urobuchi#Trivia). There are actually quite a few interviews with him that bring some light to his choices about the script, and he never mentioned lyrics.
Short answer then: very unlikely.

Edit: As comments states. This does not apply to the movies' openings.

Comment: but the question refers to the OPs of the movies *"The lyrics of Luminous by Claris, the OP for the first two movies, strikes me in particular"* and when i heard about the movie remakes it was accompanied by the announcement that there would be a third movie following them. and by "original series" i think they refer to the anime, not the movies (to which the question never does mention Connect by ClariS which is the OP for the anime)

Comment: Memor-X is right - while Rebellion wasn't planned when the original TV series came out in early 2011, Rebellion certainly _was_ planned for at the same time that movies 1 and 2 were planned, meaning that it's very likely that the lyrics to Luminous were written with at least some notion of the plot of Rebellion.